# React iterating over nested array gives error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: arrays, reactjs, iteration

I am getting an error, when trying to map over an nested array: The data structure is as follows:

**Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')**

```
export const testData = [
  {
    "date": [
      "2016-09-0912:00:00",
      "2015-09-0913:10:00"
    ],
    "title": [
      {
        "name": 'Name 1',
        "description": [
          {
            "value": 7898
          },
          {
            "value": 7898
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": 'Name 2',
        "description": [
          {
            "value": 3244
          },
          {
            "value": 4343
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": 'Name 3',
        "description": [
          null,
          null
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried:

```
 <div style={{ color: 'white' }}>
    Hello
    {testData.map(inner => {
      return (
        <p style={{color: 'white'}}>{inner.title.map(inside => {
          return (
          inside.description.map(point => {
            return (
              point.value
            )
          })
          )
        })}</p>
      )
    })}
  </div>
```

So a little confused ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the value is null for the `Name 3` object. A quick fix would be to use optional chaining.

ex

```js
 <div style={{ color: 'white' }}>
    Hello
    {testData.map(inner => {
      return (
        <p style={{color: 'white'}}>{inner.title.map(inside => {
          return (
          inside.description.map(point => {
            return (
              point?.value // here
            )
          })
          )
        })}</p>
      )
    })}
  </div>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-lovelace-15lzg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks, how would I return the values as an array if I wanted to?

Comment: As in Array of numbers = [1212321, 12312313] etc

Comment: Do you mean if the `description.value` is an array?

Comment: Yes but return an array for each description

Comment: If you're aiming to achieve the same effect, the same code works. I've changed the codesandbox to reflect this (check the first value for Name 2)

Comment: Sorry what I meant was to return an array for each description which includes the values in the array.