# Map over nested array but return an array of the numbers in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Following on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227044/react-iterating-over-nested-array-gives-error-cannot-read-properties-of-null-re/69227330#69227330)

I would like to return the point?.value as an array of numbers, I have tried `let data = point?.value + 1`

So far my code is:

Data structure:

```
export const testData = [
  {
    "date": [
      "2016-09-0912:00:00",
      "2015-09-0913:10:00"
    ],
    "title": [
      {
        "name": 'Name 1',
        "description": [
          {
            "value": 7898
          },
          {
            "value": 7898
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": 'Name 2',
        "description": [
          {
            "value": 3244
          },
          {
            "value": 4343
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": 'Name 3',
        "description": [
          null,
          null
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

map function:

```
 <div style={{ color: 'white' }}>
Hello
{testData.map(inner => {
  return (
    <p style={{color: 'white'}}>{inner.title.map(inside => {
      return (
      inside.description.map(point => {
        return (
          point?.value
        )
      })
      )
    })}</p>
  )
})}
```

Comment: What's the question? What did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

> The `flatMap()` method returns a new array formed by applying a given callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening the result by one level.

```js
const testData = [
  {
    date: ["2016-09-0912:00:00", "2015-09-0913:10:00"],
    title: [
      {
        name: "Name 1",
        description: [{ value: 7898 }, { value: 7898 }],
      },
      {
        name: "Name 2",
        description: [{ value: 3244 }, { value: 4343 }],
      },
      {
        name: "Name 3",
        description: [null, null],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const output = testData
  .flatMap((inner) => {
    return inner.title.flatMap((inside) =>
      inside.description.map((point) => point?.value)
    );
  })
  .filter((v) => typeof v !== "undefined");
console.log("output: ", output);
```

Result:

```
output:  [ 7898, 7898, 3244, 4343 ]
```

Comment: So ok, another twist what if I wanted a separate array for each description?